# Repeating variables smiley face

Tags: javascript

I'm having issues with repeating variables with this program on Khan Academy. Program seems to run fine but message informs "two or more variables have the same name. As best practice you should use different names for your variables." I can't figure it out for the life of me.

```
    var SmileyFace = function(centerX, centerY) {
        this.centerX = centerX;
        this.centerY = centerY;
    };

    SmileyFace.prototype.draw = function() {
        fill(255, 234, 0);
        ellipse(this.centerX, this.centerY, 150, 150);
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        ellipse(this.centerX-30, this.centerY-30, 20, 20);
        ellipse(this.centerX+30, this.centerY-30, 20, 20);
        noFill();
        strokeWeight(3);
        arc(this.centerX, this.centerY+10, 64, 40, 0, 180);
    };

    var face = new SmileyFace(200,300);
    face.draw();

    SmileyFace.prototype.speak = function(phrase) {
        text(phrase, this.centerX+100, this.centerY, 100, 100);
    };

    var Smiley = new SmileyFace(100, 300);
    face.draw();
    face.speak("hello");

    var face = new SmileyFace(100, 100);
    face.draw();
    face.speak("Yolo");

    var face = new SmileyFace (90,200);
    face.draw();
    face.speak("Hi");
```

Comment: try using different names for `face` variable like `face_hello, face_hi`

Answer (score 4):

You have `face` variable declared and initialised 3 times.

```
var face = new SmileyFace(200,300);
var face = new SmileyFace(100, 100);
var face = new SmileyFace (90,200);
```

Give them different names. May be `face1, face2 and face3`.

Answer (score 3):

You're redeclaring the `face` variable 3 times. If you just want to reassign it, there's no need to redeclare it:

```
var face = new SmileyFace(200,300);
// ...

face = new SmileyFace(100, 100);
// ...
```

Alternatively, use a new variable for each instance:

```
var face1 = new SmileyFace(200,300);
// ...

var face2 = new SmileyFace(100, 100);
// ...
```